# Return folders + files using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make this javascript code (made by Esailija) to write folders as well

http://jsfiddle.net/JwgqC/

Currently it only shows files, not folders.. Folders appear as dots..

Here's my mod

http://jsfiddle.net/JwgqC/46/

```
function selectFolder(e) {
    var theFiles = e.target.files;
    for (var i=0, file; file=theFiles[i]; i++) {
    document.body.innerHTML+="<li>" + file.webkitRelativePath;
    }
}
document.querySelector("input").onchange = function() {
    [].slice.call( this.files ).forEach( function(selectFolder) {
          $("body").append("<div>"+v.name+"</div>" );
    });        
};
```

But i can't get the folders to show up..
Mind pointing me which part is incorrect?

My background isn't exactly programing so it's kinda difficult for me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to display the folders only:
http://jsfiddle.net/F6yEW/

```
function isFolder(x) {
    if (x.name == "." && x.type == "") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
document.querySelector("input").onchange = function () {
    [].slice.call(this.files).forEach(function (v) {
        var folderName = "";
        var path = v.webkitRelativePath.replace("/.", "");
        if (isFolder(v)) {
            folderName = path.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/)[1];
            $("body").append("<div>" + folderName + "</div>");
        }
    });
};
```

If you would like to display folders + files: http://jsfiddle.net/K22RT/

```
function isFolder(x) {
    if (x.name == "." && x.type == "") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
document.querySelector("input").onchange = function () {
    [].slice.call(this.files).forEach(function (v) {
        var displayName = v.name;
        var path = v.webkitRelativePath.replace("/.", "");
        if (isFolder(v)) {
            displayName = path.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/)[1];
            $("body").append("<div>folder: " + displayName + "</div>");
        } else {
            $("body").append("<div>file: " + displayName + "</div>");
        }
    });
};
```

I hope this solution can help you out :)

Comment: Good Job! This lists folder only but i think i can combine it with the original code.. thanks alot pal :D